# Two media queries, same stylesheet, both work on Chrome, only on Firefox

Tags: css, media-queries

i have started designing media queries for responsive design of a page. i have written 2 media queries which are as follows:

```
      @media only screen and 
      (min-device-width : 320px)and 
      (max-device-width : 480px) {
        #loginTable {
          margin-left: 27%;
        }

        .slider-wrapper {
          margin-left: 23%;
          margin-top: 5%;
          width: 52%;
          }

        .descriptionText1 {
          margin-left: 12%;
          font-size: 59%;
          margin-top: 13%;
         }

       .header {
         margin-bottom: 4%;
        }
       .descriptionText2 {
          margin: 5% 0px 15% 12%;
          font-size: 61%;
        }
   }

     @media only screen and 
     (min-device-width : 768px) and 
     (max-device-width : 1024px) {
       #loginTable {
          border-color: rgb(204, 24, 24); 
          margin-top:2%; 
          margin-left: 2%;
        }

      .slider-wrapper {
           margin-left: 47%;
           margin-top: -31%;
       } 

       .descriptionText1 {
          margin-left: 4%;
       }

       .descriptionText2 {
           margin: 1% 0px 0px 4%; 

        }
 }
```

both the media queries are working fine on chrome, but the first media query is not working on firefox, whereas second query gives output as expected on firefox.
i tried using hacks only for first media query,

```
               <style>
                 @-moz-document url-prefix() {
                     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"               href="css/responsive.css">
                  }
               </style>
```

but the second query works fine on chrome as well as firefox without hacks. so i guess hack is not the solution. please help.

thanks

Comment: Are you testing on mobile or something larger? `max-DEVICE-width: 480px` will not trigger on a large screen no matter how you resize your browser window. Perhaps you want `max-width: 480px` instead

Comment: i am testing it on my laptop for both the browsers, on chrome by inspecting element and for firefox by using responsive design view.